# How to send email to all users who have an attribute as true (Rails Mailer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, newsletter

I'm trying to send email newsletters to all users who have left "subscribe to newsletter" checked when they registered. "Subscribed" is the boolean attribute of "Users" that I'd like to use to accomplish this.

So far I have the following.

**The error:**

```
undefined method `subscribed?' for #<Array:0x007f37ba707828>
        mail to: User.pluck(:email).subscribed?
```

**In my mailer:**

```
class Monthly_Mailer < ApplicationMailer
    def monthly(newsletter)
        @newsletter = newsletter
        mail to: User.pluck(:email).subscribed?
    end
end
```

I've tried taking off the '?' and have tried placing the following method in both my `users` `model` and `controller`

```
def subscribed?
    true if self.subscribed == true
end
```

Of course, I changed `self` to `@user` in the controller and selected the `@user` by `id`.

Please let me know if I should post additional code. I'd just like to know the best way to go about this goal, and am not necessarily attached to this way of doing it.

Thanks in advance for your input.

**EDIT: Added error**

> **NoMethodError in NewslettersController#send_newsletter**
>   **undefined method `ascii_only?' for 1:Fixnum**
>
> Monthly_Mailer.monthly(@newsletter).deliver_now

```
Started GET "/send_newsletter?id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-07 11:30:20 -0400
Started GET "/send_newsletter?id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-07 11:30:20 -0400
Processing by NewslettersController#send_newsletter as HTML
Processing by NewslettersController#send_newsletter as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Newsletter Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "newsletters".* FROM "newsletters" WHERE "newsletters"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Newsletter Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "newsletters".* FROM "newsletters" WHERE "newsletters"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE "users"."subscribed" = 't'
   (0.2ms)  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE "users"."subscribed" = 't'
  Rendered monthly_mailer/monthly.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.3ms)
  Rendered monthly_mailer/monthly.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.3ms)

Monthly_Mailer#monthly: processed outbound mail in 5.4ms

Monthly_Mailer#monthly: processed outbound mail in 5.4ms

Sent mail to  (0.5ms)

Sent mail to  (0.5ms)


Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `ascii_only?' for 1:Fixnum):
  app/controllers/newsletters_controller.rb:8:in `send_newsletter'



NoMethodError (undefined method `ascii_only?' for 1:Fixnum):
  app/controllers/newsletters_controller.rb:8:in `send_newsletter'
```

Comment: any method that has a question mark at the end is meant to return a `Boolean`.. so mind that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html (Section 2.3.3 Sending Email To Multiple Recipients)

The list of emails can be an array of email addresses or a single string with the addresses separated by commas.

1) Define a function in User model like:

```
def self.subscribed_users
  User.where(subscribed: true)
end
```

2) In your mailer, you should be doing this,

```
def monthly(newsletter)
    @newsletter = newsletter
    mail to: User.subscribed_users.pluck(:email)
    # uncomment the below line and comment above line to get comma separated emails
    # mail to: User.subscribed_users.collect(&:email).join(',')
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was having a hard time interpreting the guides for what I wanted to do so I definitely appreciate all your help. This seems like the best answer

Answer (score 2):

Use this if you want to send 1 email with all or your subscribers in the `to` field.

```
mail(to: User.where(subscribed: true).pluck(:email))
```

Use this if you want an individual email per subscriber

```
User.where(subscribed: true).pluck(:email).each do |email|
  mail(to: email)
end
```

The reason you are getting the `ascii_only?` error is because @user3683877 s answer is passing an array of ids not email addresses.

Comment: This is the type of answer I was looking for. I figured I might have to use `pluck`. Thank you very much for your input!

Comment: @Nickdb93 You don't /have/ to use pluck, it just optimises the query.

Comment: what do you think of Vamsi's answer?

Comment: @Nickdb93 its the same as mine just broken out onto the model. Only comment i have on it is the naming of the function. It returns a list of emails not users.

Comment: @DickieBoy That was a good catch though...Corrected my answer accordingly. Its same indeed. I just changed it as OP had that requirement.  He mentioned the same in Ugo Mare's answer comments.

Answer (score 1):

Ok if you want to use pluck:
 `mail to: User.where(activated: true).pluck(:email)`

For a better code use a scope instead of `where(activated: true)`

`#user.rb
scope :activated, -> { where(activated: true) }`

And then 
 `mail to: User.activated.pluck(:email)`

Comment: He probably want's a combination of what he has and what you have put. `mail to: User.where(subscribed: true).pluck(:email)`

Comment: I believe so. I've used this before so I'm not quite sure why I didn't think to try it. Let me check it and confirm. It'll take a few minutes for the email to go though (I'm not using mailcatcher atm)

Comment: @japed yes, I would like the ability to create a separate method for Users that would in effect allow me to customize the `email list" without having to change the mailer each time, however, his solution is so concise and effective I simply didn't think of it first. For example, I have another boolean attribute for `users` called `activated`, and I'd like to avoid wasting resources sending emails to users where it is `false`. I could always do `User.all.where(subscribed: true, activated: true)`, but in the future, if for some reason there are more attrs, it could be troublesome.

Comment: @japed I've got some troublesome news. The newsletter is now only being sent to one user, with no rhyme or reason. There are several users that satisfy the requirements, and the user who's receiving the newsletter has no special characteristics.

Comment: Basically, with the code you posted, only one user is being selected and sent the email, whereas I need ALL users who satisfy the requirements to get selected.

Answer (score 1):

First what you got wrong:

1) In your mailer action, you are plucking email of users which will eventually return you an array of emails and then you are chaining a **subscribed?** function which you have defined in User class. So, it is bound to pop an error.

```
User.pluck(:email).subscribed?
```

Solution:

1) Define a function in User model like:

```
def self.subscribed_users
  User.where(subscribed: true).pluck(:email)
end
```

2) In your mailer, you can call like this:

```
def monthly(newsletter)
        @newsletter = newsletter
        mail to: User.subscribed_users
end
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for! I just wasn't sure how to go about it. With the above code, however, I get an error while sending out the email: `undefined method 'ascii_only?' for 1:Fixnum` on `Monthly_Mailer.monthly(@newsletter).deliver_now` I know this probably has to do with the `deliver_now` method, but why is this error being called NOW? Is it because of `.ids` in `def self.subscribed_users`?

Comment: I updated my answer bellow with pluck like you wanted.
` User.where(subscribed: true).ids ` returns an array of ids so you can directly mail to with. That's will you have `undefined method 'ascii_only?'`

Comment: sorry for the typo, i meant .pluck(:email) instead of .ids

Comment: Check out Vamsi's answer